Determine inductive elements in transformer model

A model of a single phase, \$500 \text{V} / 6 \text{V} \$ two winding transformer, with an ideal transformer in the middle is seen below


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Equipped with an LRC meter with variable frequency (100 Hz to 10 kHz) determine \$L_1, L_2, L_m\$. I am allowed to short the terminals.

Attempt
If I set the frequency of the LRC meter to 100 Hz, I can with good reason consider the capacitors as open circuits.
I can determine \$L_2 \$ by shorting the primary side, and measuring L on the secondary side. I got approximately \$16 \: \mu\text{H}\$.
I can also determine \$L_m\$ approximately, by shorting the secondary side and measuring L on the primary side. \$L_m \$ is likely to be much greater than \$L_1\$ (I believe) so when measuring L on the primary side, the value of \$L_m\$ will dominate. I got approximately 2 H.
However, I have been unable to determine how to measure \$L_1\$. What can I do to get the value of \$L_1\$ with what I have available?

Maybe you can sweep the frequency of the LRC meter and try to find a resonant frequencies of the circuit. This can be done for multiple scenarios (open/short of terminals). From the resulting resonant frequencies, you can try to calculate the inductor and capacitor values. Seems not to be an easy task...

What are your data values?

@Antonio51 You mean the values I measured for L2 and Lm? I edited the question to include the values.

No, it's harder than that.

Sure, at low frequencies you can ignore the capacitors but, when you perform shorted winding tests you get L1+L2 and neither can be individually separated by testing alone.

So, if you short the secondary and use an LCR bridge/meter on the primary, because the magnetization inductance is so much higher in value than the leakage inductance, what you effectively measure on the primary is L1 in series with the primary referred value for L2.

But all is not lost because, if both windings are wound pretty much using the same technique, what you can say is that half the measured inductance equals exactly L1 (with the remainder being the primary referred secondary inductance L2).

Given that you know the turns ratio, you can then establish what L2 is using half the measured value and divide it by the step-down turns ratio squared.

Then you should repeat from the secondary side to check the numbers match up. Of course they won't be a perfect match but, they should be within a couple of percent. Use the step-up ratio squared at this point to establish L1.

To measure magnetization inductance use the LCR bridge on the primary and leave the secondary open-circuit.


All done at the lowest frequency of the LCR bridge.
